# Does BitcoinABC implement replay protection for the upcoming November 15th hardfork

Tags: bitcoin-cash, replay-attack, ecash

Does BitcoinABC implement replay protection for the upcoming November 15th hardfork. With the arguing between the two camps BitcoinABC and BitcoinSV will replay protection be implemented before the split?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not related to Bitcoin.

Comment: Why not? A replay attack can work both ways, right? One can spend a forkcoin and without realizing spend actual bitcoins? So it's a valid concern for bitcoin users?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there's `OP_CHECKDATASIG` in ABC's code and `OP_MUL` in SV's code.

There's already a [coin splitting tool](https://redd.it/9ul7mp).